# How to add a row to a pandas dataframe with interval indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can you add a row to a dataframe in pandas with interval indices in both the column and index?

I am trying to define the total counts in a crosstable in pandas defined as:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(500,2))
bins = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)
df['bins_0'] = pd.cut(df[0], bins=bins)
df['bins_1'] = pd.cut(df[1], bins=bins)
# Define crosstable
ct = pd.crosstab(df['bins_0'], df['bins_1'])
# define sumrow
sumrow = ct.sum(axis=0)
```

My question is: how can you include a row in such a table?

*What I tried so far:*

Using '.loc' to add a row does not work.

`ct.loc['total'] = sumrow`

results in
`TypeError: cannot append a non-category item to a CategoricalIndex`

Trying to reset the index also did not work in this case, since using 'ct.reset_index()'
resulted in `TypeError: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category`

In the end I would also add a column with the sums per row, but I suppose that would require the same procedure as adding a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is use `margins` in [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
ct = pd.crosstab(df['bins_0'], df['bins_1'], margins=True, margins_name='Total')
```

Your solution -  if need new column `Total` add categories to columns and `axis=1` to `sum`:

```
ct = pd.crosstab(df['bins_0'], df['bins_1'])
ct.columns = ct.columns.add_categories('Total')
ct['Total'] = ct.sum(axis=1)
```

Or add [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) if need new `Total` row:

```
ct = pd.crosstab(df['bins_0'], df['bins_1'])
ct.index= ct.index.add_categories('Total')
ct.loc['Total'] = ct.sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks, the margins function on crosstab works great.

Comment: Also, I edited the question because I made a mistake not to use `.loc` as I had written `ct.index= ct.index.add_categories('Total')
ct['Total'] = ct.sum(axis=0)`